# how to prevent resizing of items in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, instagram

I have a heterogeneous recyclerview (Image, video and text) it is working fine but the problem is when i scroll, it resizes according to the height of posts. so how can i make it like instagram as when we rapidly scroll in instagram even though the posts are not loaded but they occupy their height already and not resize, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

make sure that on your ViewHolders height isn't set on wrapContent when it happened your viewHolder change its size to what ever you are passing to it
i recommend to use ConstraintLayout to make better views
see the docs for more info
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout

Comment: thank you @ErfanDP but can you elaborate or share any code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the parent view group of the item's height that recycled isn't set to

```
android:layout_height="wrapContent"
```